# GERRIT_REFSPEC is always empty in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I've set up a Jenkins pipeline in which I want to run a Jenkinsfile, based on a Gerrit trigger. I have read a lot on here about how to set this up. I have added the `GERRIT_REFSPEC` variable as parameter and `$GERRIT_REFSPEC` under Advanced->Refspec in my pipeline.

The issue is that `GERRIT_REFSPEC` is always empty when I trigger a build from Gerrit. I would expect it to contain something like `"refs/changes/../.../."`. `GERRIT_BRANCH` and other variables are set correctly. Even when I trigger a build from Jenkins by running `"Build with parameters"` and overwrite the value, it's empty afterwards.

I have seen the error, because the Git checkout goes wrong. I've also tried creating a pipeline script directly in Jenkins and echoing multiple Gerrit parameters there. `GERRIT_REFSPEC` seems the only one that's empty. All other variables contain valid information.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Are you triggering the build manually? The GERRIT_REFSPEC variable will not set automatically this way but you can use the "Jenkins" > "Query and Trigger Gerrit Patches" to do that. By the other side, I think this should work if you create the variable throught a parameter.

Comment: No, I'm triggering the build by uploading a change to Gerrit. I've also triggered the build manually and filled in a parameter manually. I could see that it is still empty in that case.

Comment: Can you confirm that you’re using the Gerrit Trigger plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=45481993)?  If so, is your build triggered by a “Ref Updated” event?  From the doc: Note: Be aware that $GERRIT_BRANCH and $GERRIT_REFSPEC are not set in the Ref Updated case. If you want to trigger a build, you can set Refspec and 'Branches to build' to $GERRIT_REFNAME.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more when a "Ref updated" event is triggered and what other options are?

Comment: I haven't changed anything on the Gerrit configuration. We use this for normal Jenkins projects as well. We also use the REFSPEC there. The only difference here is that I've set up a pipeline project. So the 'sending' side (being Git/Gerrit) is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the Lightweight checkout:

[image]